# My checkbox is not changing from check or uncheck, but I can see that state value is changing, what's going on?

Tags: reactjs

So when I run this and check the checkbox, I can see the values changing in the state, but why is the checkbox control not changing its status from check/uncheck? I know the render() method is being hit as well. Why, oh why, Gods of code? Lost in hours of figuring out what's wrong and I'm lost!

bob-Todos.js FILE

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor(param) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      id: param.data.id,
      text: param.data.text,
      completed: param.data.completed,
      onMyChange: param.OnChange,
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log("In TODO Render");
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={() => {
              this.state.onMyChange(this.state.id);
            }}
            checked={this.state.completed}
          />
          {this.state.text}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

Bob-App.js FILE

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Todo from "./bob-Todo";
import todoData from "../data/bob-todosData";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { data: todoData };

    this.OnChange = this.OnChange.bind(this);
  }

  OnChange(myId) {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      let updatedTodos = prev.data.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === myId) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo;
      });
      return { data: updatedTodos };
    });

    console.log(this.state.data);
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.data.map((item) => {
      return <Todo key={item.id} data={item} OnChange={this.OnChange} />;
    });
  }
}
export default App;
```

bob-todosData.js FILE

```
const todosData = [
    {
        id: 1, 
        text: "take out the trash",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2, 
        text: "rest for a while and relax",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 3, 
        text: "watch an online movie",
        completed: true
    }
]

export default todosData
```

index.js FILE

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppBob from "./bobComponents/Bob-App";

ReactDOM.render(
    <AppBob />, document.getElementById('root') 
);
```

Comment: in Todo component, props changed, but state not, replace `this.state.completed` with `this.props.completed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **You don't need to assign your `props` to `state` in your `Todo` component**

Just remove them and invoke the function also use those variables directly:

**Then your component will be:**

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      data: {
        id,
        text,
        completed,
      },
      OnChange, // <-- Should rename this to "onChange"
    } = this.props;
    console.log('In TODO Render');
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={() => {
              OnChange(id);
            }}
            checked={completed}
          />
          {text}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

---

Also, rename your `OnChange` function to `onChange` to enable [js convention](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)

Comment: I'm the one who wrote the EDIT section above, I don't know how to properly put a long comment with code, if you can edit it again, thanks

Comment: Hey @Datadump, I read your edit, There was a mistake with OnChange object destructure, I updated the answer, see if it works.

Comment: The `,` is just an annoying [eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle) but it doesn't hurt so...

Comment: Thanks man, that revised code works now, really appreciate the help, struggling with front-end. cheers

Comment: Superf! If you find this helpful, you can mark this as accepted, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Ryan, just a closing question, though everything is working now, just want to be enlightened why I can't reference the "data" after destructuring it, like data.id or data.text? why the direct the access like id,or text or completed? (perhaps this question merits another thread but just trying it here..) Thanks

Comment: Yes, you obviously can. When I wrote `data: { id, text, completed, }`. The `data` is just an access point for `id, text, completed` to access to, that is how object destructuring works. If you want to have direct access to data. Then declare another one like: `data, data: { id, text, completed, }`. By doing so, you still have direct access and also children variables.

Comment: If data is an access point, and it's an object, should it be something like data.id? that data is an object variable with 3 properties, quite confusing.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to name the `data` in `data: { id, text, completed}` Just only know that, the data is only available for children variable are `id, text, completed` :D